# Create a Ansible dictionary which keeps order

Tags: python, ansible

How could I create dictionary with order?

I have dictionary as

```
vars:
  myDict:
    Bob: 30
    Alice: 20
```

How could I keep `"Bob"` in front of `"Alice"`? Ansible orders this map for me based on key letters

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this. Please, search for "python dict order".

You can only replace your original dict with a list:

```
myListofDict:
  - key: Bob
    value: 30
  - key: Alice
    value: 20
```